# How can I deselect all selected option of a dropdown when selecting an option in a different dropdown?

Tags: drop-down-menu, combobox, office365, powerapps

I am having two `dropdown menus/ comboboxes` on which I can select content which I wanna display on a `DataTable`.

The first `Combobox` is called `ColorCombo` and gets the following options to choose from  an Excel sheet:

```
Sort(Distinct(Table3;Color);Result;Ascending).
```

The second Combobox is called SizeCombo and gets the following options to choose from an Excel sheet:

```
Sort(Distinct(Table3;Size);Result;Ascending).
```

My question is how can I make my code work so that each time I choose a color on one dropdown, then all options from the other dropdown are being deselected? I tried to reset the comboboxes when the onChange even triggered as follows:

```
ColorCombo onChange : Reset(SizeCombo)
SizeCombo onChange : Reset(ColorCombo)
```

But this doesn't work because every time I choose a new option then all options from the drop-downs are being unselected because the events trigger each other. Could someone help understand how I could go about it?

Answer (score 1):

If  you can only have a value in either one of the drop downs, you could make the onChange variable of each one set the DisplayMode of the other one to Disabled. eg:

```
ColorCombo onChange : SizeCombo DisplayMode.Disabled
SizeCombo onChange : ColorCombo DisplayMode.Disabled
```

Sorry if I misunderstood your question!